# Script to export layer coordinates to excel

Tags: export, export-to-excel

I have found a script that export my layers coordinates form photoshop CS5 to XML
I hope somebody here can help me to edit that script to record coordinates to xls file?
Also if is possible to have each coordinates on separate row will be great.
Below is script I want to modify to do what I need.

```
//
// This script exports extended layer.bounds information to [psd_file_name].xml
// by pattesdours
//

function docCheck() {
    // ensure that there is at least one document open
    if (!documents.length) {
        alert('There are no documents open.');
        return; // quit
    }
}

docCheck();

var originalRulerUnits = preferences.rulerUnits;
preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;

var docRef = activeDocument;

var docWidth = docRef.width.value;
var docHeight = docRef.height.value;
var mySourceFilePath = activeDocument.fullName.path + "/";

//  Code to get layer index / descriptor
//
cTID = function(s) { return app.charIDToTypeID(s); };
sTID = function(s) { return app.stringIDToTypeID(s); };
function getLayerDescriptor (doc, layer) {
    var ref = new ActionReference();
    ref.putEnumerated(cTID("Lyr "), cTID("Ordn"), cTID("Trgt"));
    return executeActionGet(ref)
};

function getLayerID(doc, layer) {
  var d = getLayerDescriptor(doc, layer);
  return d.getInteger(cTID('LyrI'));
};

var stackorder = 0;

// function from Xbytor to traverse all layers
traverseLayers = function(doc, ftn, reverse) {
  function _traverse(doc, layers, ftn, reverse) {
    var ok = true;
    for (var i = 1; i <= layers.length && ok != false; i++) {
      var index = (reverse == true) ? layers.length-i : i - 1;
      var layer = layers[index];

      if (layer.typename == "LayerSet") {
        ok = _traverse(doc, layer.layers, ftn, reverse);

      } else {
  stackorder = stackorder + 1;
        ok = ftn(doc, layer, stackorder);
      }
    }
    return ok;
  };

  return _traverse(doc, doc.layers, ftn, reverse);
};

// create a string to hold the data
var str ="";

// class using a contructor
function cLayer(doc, layer) {

//this.layerID = Stdlib.getLayerID(doc, layer);
    this.layerID = getLayerID(doc, layer);
  //alert("layer ID: " + this.layerID);
    this.layerWidth = layer.bounds[2].value - layer.bounds[0].value;
      this.layerHeight = layer.bounds[3].value - layer.bounds[1].value;

    // these return object coordinates relative to canvas
      this.upperLeftX = layer.bounds[0].value;
      this.upperLeftY = layer.bounds[1].value;
      this.upperCenterX = this.layerWidth / 2 + layer.bounds[0].value;
      this.upperCenterY = layer.bounds[1].value;
      this.upperRightX = layer.bounds[2].value;
      this.upperRightY = layer.bounds[1].value;
      this.middleLeftX = layer.bounds[0].value;
      this.middleLeftY = this.layerHeight / 2 + layer.bounds[1].value;
      this.middleCenterX = this.layerWidth / 2 + layer.bounds[0].value;
      this.middleCenterY = this.layerHeight / 2 + layer.bounds[1].value;
      this.middleRightX = layer.bounds[2].value;
      this.middleRightY = this.layerHeight / 2 + layer.bounds[1].value;
      this.lowerLeftX = layer.bounds[0].value;
      this.lowerLeftY = layer.bounds[3].value;
      this.lowerCenterX = this.layerWidth / 2 + layer.bounds[0].value;
      this.lowerCenterY = layer.bounds[3].value;
      this.lowerRightX = layer.bounds[2].value;
      this.lowerRightY = layer.bounds[3].value;

      // I'm adding these for easier editing of flash symbol transformation point (outputs a 'x, y' format)
      // because I like to assign shortcut keys that use the numeric pad keyboard, like such:
      //        7   8   9
      //        4   5   6
      //        1   2   3
      //
      this.leftBottom = this.lowerLeftX + ", " + this.lowerLeftY;
      this.bottomCenter = this.lowerCenterX + ", " + this.lowerCenterY;
      this.rightBottom = this.lowerRightX + ", " + this.lowerRightY;

      this.leftCenter = this.middleLeftX + ", " + this.middleLeftY;
      this.center = this.middleCenterX + ", " + this.middleCenterY;
      this.rightCenter = this.middleRightX + ", " + this.middleRightY;

      this.leftTop = this.upperLeftX + ", " + this.upperLeftY;
      this.topCenter = this.upperCenterX + ", " + this.upperCenterY;
      this.rightTop = this.upperRightX + ", " + this.upperRightY;

    // these return object coordinates relative to layer bounds
      this.relUpperLeftX = layer.bounds[1].value - layer.bounds[1].value;
      this.relUpperLeftY =  layer.bounds[0].value - layer.bounds[0].value;
      this.relUpperCenterX = this.layerWidth / 2;
      this.relUpperCenterY = layer.bounds[0].value - layer.bounds[0].value;
      this.relUpperRightX = this.layerWidth;
      this.relUpperRightY = layer.bounds[0].value - layer.bounds[0].value;
      this.relMiddleLeftX = layer.bounds[1].value - layer.bounds[1].value;
      this.relMiddleLeftY = this.layerHeight / 2;
      this.relMiddleCenterX = this.layerWidth / 2;
      this.relMiddleCenterY = this.layerHeight / 2;
      this.relMiddleRightX = this.layerWidth;
    this.relMiddleRightY = this.layerHeight / 2;
      this.relLowerLeftX = layer.bounds[1].value - layer.bounds[1].value;
      this.relLowerLeftY = this.layerHeight;
      this.relLowerCenterX = this.layerWidth / 2;
    this.relLowerCenterY = this.layerHeight / 2;
      this.relLowerRightY = this.layerHeight;
      this.relLowerRightX = this.layerWidth;
      this.relLowerRightY = this.layerHeight;

  return this;
}

// add header line
//str = "<psd filename=\"" + docRef.name + "\" path=\"" + mySourceFilePath + "\" width=\"" + docWidth + "\" height=\"" + docHeight + "\">\n";

// now a function to collect the data
function exportBounds(doc, layer, i) {
    var isVisible = layer.visible;
    var layerData = cLayer(doc, layer);

 // if(isVisible){
// Layer object main coordinates relative to its active pixels
    var str2 = leftTop // this is the 
//  + "\" layerwidth=\"" + layerData.layerWidth 
//  + "\" layerheight=\"" + layerData.layerHeight 
//  + "\" transformpoint=\"" + "center" + "\">" // hard-coding 'center' as the default transformation point 
    +"\"  \""  + layer.name + ".png" + "</layer>\n" // I have to put some content here otherwise sometimes tags are ignored
str += str2.toString();
   };
//};


// call X's function using the one above
traverseLayers(app.activeDocument, exportBounds, true);

// Use this to export XML file to same directory where PSD file is located
    var mySourceFilePath = activeDocument.fullName.path + "/";
// create a reference to a file for output
    var csvFile = new File(mySourceFilePath.toString().match(/([^\.]+)/)[1] + app.activeDocument.name.match(/([^\.]+)/)[1] + ".xls");
// open the file, write the data, then close the file
csvFile.open('w');
csvFile.writeln(str + "</psd>");
csvFile.close();
preferences.rulerUnits = originalRulerUnits;
// Confirm that operation has completed
alert("Operation Complete!" + "\n" + "Layer coordinates were successfully exported to:" + "\n" + "\n" + mySourceFilePath.toString().match(/([^\.]+)/)[1] + app.activeDocument.name.match(/([^\.]+)/)[1] + ".xml");
```

Comment: Don't suppose you got this working by any chance?

Comment: No I did not make it worked, is far too complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
var str2 = leftTop // this is the 
//  + "\" layerwidth=\"" + layerData.layerWidth 
//  + "\" layerheight=\"" + layerData.layerHeight 
//  + "\" transformpoint=\"" + "center" + "\">" // hard-coding 'center' as the default transformation point 
    +"\"  \""  + layer.name + ".png" + "</layer>\n" // I have to put some content here otherwise sometimes tags are ignored
str += str2.toString();
```

to

```
var str2 = leftTop + ","+ layer.name + "\n" 
   str += str2.toString();
```

and

```
var csvFile = new File(mySourceFilePath.toString().match(/([^\.]+)/)[1] + app.activeDocument.name.match(/([^\.]+)/)[1] + ".xls");
```

to

```
var csvFile = new File(mySourceFilePath.toString().match(/([^\.]+)/)[1] + app.activeDocument.name.match(/([^\.]+)/)[1] + ".csv");
```

This works great for me!