# How to get plotted point coordinates from layer in Fireworks or Photoshop

Tags: photoshop, fireworks

I have an image with two layers. The first layer is a background image. The second layer contains multiple circles scattered around. I would like to know how in can extract the x,y values of the circles to a text file. Should I be using a different tool?  If so which one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this. It's a little complex, but it does just what I need.

1)  In Fireworks make sure that the objects you want mapped are in their own layer.  It makes it easier if you give the layer a meaningful name(not required)

2)  Save the Fireworks document as a .psd file

3)  Go to this url: [Script to export layer coordinates to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052779/script-to-export-layer-coordinates-to-excel/36958170#36958170) and copy the script there and make modifications I added in my answer.

4)  Load the script into Photoshop(instructions on web)

5)  If Photoshop was open, then close it.

6)  Reopen Photoshop

7)  Run the script from the "File/Scripts/" menu

8) Voila, a csv file that will read into a spreadsheet program, which contains the x,y value of the object and the object's name